# AJAX Проблема с CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, cors

У меня есть апи для сайта, которое расположено на другом хостинге. AJAX запросы выполняю с помощью Jquery, но какие либо параметры я не передавал из источника интернета для решения этой проблемы crossDomain: true, header заголовки, браузер блокирует запрос и выводит стандартную ошибку об политике cors. Может ли быть это причина на стороне сервера? Или есть какие нибудь другие решения?

Comment: Cors это сторона стороннего сервера либо пишите на своем бекенде запрос к стороннему серверу.

Answer (score 0):

Браузер блокирует запросы с разных доменов, самый простой вариант использовать прокси. [Cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) поможет. Просто добавляйте `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` перед ссылкой на нужный API.